# does anybody see wrong with my update or insert queries? I am using prepared statement

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement

public void insertOrUpdate(String customerNumber, Long creditLimitAmount)
        throws SQLException {

```
Connection connection2 = UBOCMSSQLConnectionUtill.getMSSqlConnection();
connection2.setAutoCommit(false);
PreparedStatement updatePreparedStatement = null;
PreparedStatement insertPreparedStatement = null;
try {
    String updateQuery = "UPDATE CRLM2 SET BR=?, LIMITTYPE =?, LIMITMEMBER=?,"
        + "PRODUCT=?,PRODTYPE=?,MTYDATE=?,CCY=?,CREQLIMAMT=?,MRKTLIMAMT=?,EXPDATE=?,"
        + "PRODGROUPID=?,AMT1=?,AMT2=?,DATE1=?,DATE2=?,TEXT1=?,TEXT2=?,LIMITSEQ=?,"
        + "STARTDATE=?,UPDATECOUNTER=? WHERE LIMITMEMBER = ?";

    String insertQuery = "insert into CRLM2(" + "BR," + "LIMITTYPE,"
        + "LIMITMEMBER," + "PRODUCT," + "PRODTYPE," + "MTYDATE,"
        + "CCY," + "CREQLIMAMT," + "MRKTLIMAMT," + "EXPDATE,"
        + "PRODGROUPID" + "AMT1," + "AMT2," + "DATE1," + "DATE2,"
        + "TEXT1," + "TEXT2," + "LIMITSEQ," + "STARTDATE,"
        + "UPDATECOUNTER) "
        + "values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

    /**
     * First try to update the row, but if that row does not exists,
     * then insert it.
     */
    updatePreparedStatement = connection2.prepareStatement(updateQuery);
    updatePreparedStatement.setString(1, "01");
    updatePreparedStatement.setString(2, "C");
    updatePreparedStatement.setString(3, customerNumber);
    updatePreparedStatement.setString(4, "FXD");
    updatePreparedStatement.setString(5, "FX");
    updatePreparedStatement.setString(6, "tbd");
    updatePreparedStatement.setString(7, "USD");
    updatePreparedStatement.setLong(8, creditLimitAmount);
    updatePreparedStatement.setNull(9, java.sql.Types.NUMERIC);
    updatePreparedStatement.setNull(10, java.sql.Types.DATE);
    updatePreparedStatement.setNull(11, java.sql.Types.CHAR);
    updatePreparedStatement.setNull(12, java.sql.Types.NUMERIC);
    updatePreparedStatement.setNull(13, java.sql.Types.NUMERIC);
    updatePreparedStatement.setNull(14, java.sql.Types.DATE);
    updatePreparedStatement.setNull(15, java.sql.Types.DATE);
    updatePreparedStatement.setNull(16, java.sql.Types.CHAR);
    updatePreparedStatement.setNull(17, java.sql.Types.CHAR);
    updatePreparedStatement.setNull(18, java.sql.Types.NUMERIC);
    updatePreparedStatement.setNull(19, java.sql.Types.DATE);
    updatePreparedStatement.setNull(20, java.sql.Types.NUMERIC);
    int count = updatePreparedStatement.executeUpdate();
    System.out.println("count value after updatePreparedStatement is "
        + count);
    connection2.commit();
    connection2.close();
    updatePreparedStatement.close();      
    Connection connection3 = UBOCMSSQLConnectionUtill
        .getMSSqlConnection();
    insertPreparedStatement = connection3.prepareStatement(insertQuery);
    connection3.setAutoCommit(false);
    if (count == 0) {
    insertPreparedStatement.setString(1, "01");
    insertPreparedStatement.setString(2, "C");
    insertPreparedStatement.setString(3, customerNumber);
    insertPreparedStatement.setString(4, "FXD");
    insertPreparedStatement.setString(5, "FX");
    insertPreparedStatement.setString(6, "tbd");
    insertPreparedStatement.setString(7, "USD");
    insertPreparedStatement.setLong(8, creditLimitAmount);
    insertPreparedStatement.setNull(9, java.sql.Types.NUMERIC);
    insertPreparedStatement.setNull(10, java.sql.Types.DATE);
    insertPreparedStatement.setNull(11, java.sql.Types.CHAR);
    insertPreparedStatement.setNull(12, java.sql.Types.NUMERIC);
    insertPreparedStatement.setNull(13, java.sql.Types.NUMERIC);
    insertPreparedStatement.setNull(14, java.sql.Types.DATE);
    insertPreparedStatement.setNull(15, java.sql.Types.DATE);
    insertPreparedStatement.setNull(16, java.sql.Types.CHAR);
    insertPreparedStatement.setNull(17, java.sql.Types.CHAR);
    insertPreparedStatement.setNull(18, java.sql.Types.NUMERIC);
    insertPreparedStatement.setNull(19, java.sql.Types.DATE);
    insertPreparedStatement.setNull(20, java.sql.Types.NUMERIC);
    insertPreparedStatement.executeUpdate();
    connection3.commit();
    }
} finally {
    if (insertPreparedStatement != null) {
    insertPreparedStatement.close();
    }
}

}
```

}

found and returning db conn
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][SQLServer 2000 Driver for JDBC]Invalid parameter binding(s).
    at com.microsoft.jdbc.base.BaseExceptions.createException(Unknown Source)
    at com.microsoft.jdbc.base.BaseExceptions.getException(Unknown Source)
    at com.microsoft.jdbc.base.BasePreparedStatement.validateParameters(Unknown Source)
    at com.microsoft.jdbc.base.BasePreparedStatement.validateParameters(Unknown Source)
    at com.microsoft.jdbc.base.BasePreparedStatement.preImplExecute(Unknown Source)
    at com.microsoft.jdbc.base.BaseStatement.commonExecute(Unknown Source)
    at com.microsoft.jdbc.base.BaseStatement.executeUpdateInternal(Unknown Source)
    at com.microsoft.jdbc.base.BasePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at com.uboc.pdealcc.dao.PDealCCDao.insertOrUpdate(PDealCCDao.java:98)
    at com.uboc.pdealcc.dao.PDealCCDao.getCustomerId(PDealCCDao.java:37)
    at com.uboc.pdealcc.processor.COpxDeal.CheckQlim(COpxDeal.java:165)
    at com.uboc.pdealcc.listeners.TablePopupListener.actionPerformed(TablePopupListener.java:130)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 21 parameters in the update query but you are only setting values for 20 of them.

---

```
    UPDATE CRLM2 SET BR=1, LIMITTYPE =2, LIMITMEMBER=3,"
    + "PRODUCT=4,PRODTYPE=5,MTYDATE=6,CCY=7,CREQLIMAMT=8,MRKTLIMAMT=9,EXPDATE=10,"
    + "PRODGROUPID=11,AMT1=12,AMT2=13,DATE1=14,DATE2=15,TEXT1=16,TEXT2=17,LIMITSEQ=18,"
    + "STARTDATE=19,UPDATECOUNTER=20 WHERE LIMITMEMBER = 21
```

Comment: @aditya86c I replaced your ? with numbers to show how many parameters you actually have.

Comment: but I still see this error  [Microsoft][SQLServer 2000 Driver for JDBC]Object has been closed.

Answer (score 0):

Vincent is right. Your update query has 21 params and your insert query has 20 params. However in your code you are only setting 20 params for your update query.

LIMITMEMBER is param number 3 and 21.

Comment: does anybody see wrong with my insert statement especially at BR

Comment: I am getting this java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][SQLServer 2000 Driver for JDBC][SQLServer]Incorrect syntax near 'BR'.